# glTexImage2D is not working when using GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE

Tags: opengl

I am trying to write a "BMP player".
My main objective is to do it fast! I need to get to 60fps.
I am loading all images to memory and then using glTexImage2D to switch the texture content.

when I use the command:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, g_width, g_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, currentlyPlatedFrame->data);
```

the movie works fine (60fps) on low resolutions (720p and lower) but it has a very low frame rate on HD or higher (I need to get to 1600p).

I did some search online and found that GL_TEXTURE_2D works on square textures with power of 2, which means that when playing 1920x1080 I am actually playing 2048x2048 (a squer with the next power of 2 after 1280) and to make my program faster I need to use GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE.

my problem is that when I change all the GL_TEXTURE_2D in my code to GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE my player shows only the first pixel on the entire screen.

is there something else that I need to change when switching from 2D to RECTANGLE?
can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? or if you have an idea on how to use GL_TEXTURE_2D but do it faster it would help me a lot.

i'm working on win7 and VS2010

my code (the relevant part):

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <glfw.h>

glfwInit();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );  
if( !glfwOpenWindow( g_width, g_height, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_FULLSCREEN ))
{
    glfwTerminate(); //terminating glfw window
    return 0;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle("Texture");
glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(handleResize);
glfwSetKeyCallback(handleKeypress);
glfwEnable(GLFW_MOUSE_CURSOR);
glfwSwapInterval(1);

glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ); //clear background screen to black

    //Clear information from last draw
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); 

    glGenTextures(1,&Texture); //allocate the memory for texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Texture); //Binding the texture

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable texture

currentlyPlatedFrame = goToFirstFrameToPlay(headOfList,startFrameNum);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,Texture);
while (1)
{ 
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, g_width, g_height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, currentlyPlatedFrame->data);

    glPushMatrix();//move out of loop
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates
    glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);//normal vector
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); //Texture co-ordinate origin or  lower left corner
    glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); //Texture co-ordinate lower right corner
    glVertex3f(1.0f,  -1.0f,0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);//Texture co-ordinate top right corner
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);//Texture co-ordinate top left corner
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates
    glPopMatrix();//move out of loop
    glFinish();//add glfinish
    glfwSwapBuffers();
    numOfPlayedFrames++;

    currentlyPlatedFrame = currentlyPlatedFrame->next;
}
```

Comment: "*I did some search online and found that GL_TEXTURE_2D works on square textures with power of 2, which means that when playing 1920x1080 I am actually playing 2048x2048*" Unless you're using a version of OpenGL less than 2.0, this is *wrong*. Textures no longer have power-of-two restrictions. Furthermore, even if there were a power-of-two restriction, the function call would have *failed*; you wouldn't get a properly created texture. So obviously it was working and you were getting a texture with the expected size.

Comment: If you're concerned about performance and are updating the texture image of the same texture object each frame and the format or size doesn't change, then you should rather use `glTexSubImage2D` istead of `glTexImage2D`, which doesn't reallocate the whole texture data each frame. I cannot guarantee that it gives a performance improvement, but it pretty well might (and will never be slower than `glTexImage2D`) and is the conceptually more correct way to do it. And of course what *Nicol* said above.

Comment: Likewise do you already have a screen sized texture, no need for linear filtering. And you might also consider using shaders instead of the fixed function pipeline. The latter might do a whole lot of unneccessary things (or at least checks if to do them or not), while the former can be customized to a pretty simple pass-through of the texture, using some 1-2 lines of code per shader. And consider switching to VBOs instead of `glBegin/glEnd`. It might not be crucial with such a simple geometry, but you never know and it won't be slower anyway.

Comment: And by all means don't call `glFinish`. It stalls the pipeline and unneccessarily waits for all GPU operations to, well, finish. If you need any kind of temporal synchronization there are way better ways to do it. So all in all there is a lot of omptimization potential in your code apart from changing the texture target, which won't buy you anything. If you're new and all those keywords from my comments don't tell you much, feel free to google them. But don't change the texture target to `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE` because you think it will result in better performance, since that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

For those visitors who came here for a solution;
When using a rectangle texture, coordinates must be specified in (0,0) - (tex_width, tex_height) range, not (0,0) - (1,1).